# COUNT (DISTINCT expression)?

Tags: sql, count, distinct

Code:

```
Select Distinct
    EE.EMPLOYEE_ID,
    EE.COLOR,
    COUNT(DISTINCT EE.COLOR) AS COLOR_COUNT
FROM #EMPLOYEEINFO EE

GROUP BY EE.EMPLOYEE_ID,
         EE.COLOR
```

I thought this code would give me the number of unique colors per employee ID. However, COLOR_COUNT comes back as 1 for all rows.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the number of unique colors, then don't include `color` in the `group by`:

```
SELECT EE.EMPLOYEE_ID, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT EE.COLOR) AS COLOR_COUNT
FROM #EMPLOYEEINFO EE
GROUP BY EE.EMPLOYEE_ID;
```

Also, you almost never need `SELECT DISTINCT` when using `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Is there a way to still select the color? As opposed to only having the count?

Comment: @ArjunArun . . . It does not make sense to select "the color" when you are counting the distinct colors.